# Can someone explain Block 9193687: Why are there so many zero gas price transactions included?

Tags: transactions, etherscan, gas-price

Block 9193687 (Link: https://etherscan.io/txs?block=9193687&p=1) contains 79 transactions, of which 75 have a gas price of 0. These transactions are also not all from the same address.

How does something like this happen? Is someone mining his own 0 gas cost transactions? But then why include other 0 cost transactions? Is it a badly configured mining client? Was the tx pool completely empty (is there a way to check that?)?

I realize most of the tx **minted** GST2 tokens, which is very advantageous to do for a low gas price, but still, a gas price of 0 seems very odd to me.

Comment: Another similar block: https://etherscan.io/block/9193804

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not forbidden.

If you think of it it kinda makes sense that a lot of 0-gas transactions are in a single block: a single miner (or a mining pool) for some reason includes lots of 0-gas transactions in the blocks he tries to mine. When he finally succeeds in mining a block all of those transactions finally go through.

I'm not sure if you can find statistics about how many non-zero transactions were in the pool at a given time. This one shows just the total amount, and even this chart has no idea if some miner was for example disconnected for a second when he tried to find other non-0-gas transactions so he couldn't see any. https://etherscan.io/chart/pendingtx

As for the real *why*, we'll most likely never know. Maybe a misconfigured client. Maybe a brief disconnect. Maybe an agreement outside blockchain (if you mine our 0-gas transactions we'll give you a million dollars).

Comment: Or maybe an agreement between one to itself (when that someone requires periodic state changes in his/her contract/contracts, and wishes to avoid high periodic expanses).